# Intellij IDEA and Flex SDK runtime shared library

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, intellij-idea, shared-libraries, rsl

I am trying to make `IntelliJ IDEA 12` configure `rsl` libraries for runtime loading.
Do you have any experience with that, and do you maybe have a sample `XML` you put into aditional compiler options?

Also, I didnt find the plugin for this, if you know any please say

update:

To clarify the practice project more:

I want to make 2 'swf's that will have one tweening library used on a simple shape, but I want to make that tweening library crossdomain rsl.

Then the goal is to in MainApp load and add to stage one swf and then the other. What I expect to happen is that the first time rsl will be loaded and the second time it will be used from cache.

I am programing in pure AS3. Examples would be wonderful :)
Right now I am trying to build one class that has RedSquare and tweening applied to that square. Ofcourse, tweening should come from rsl library.

Update 2:

I got to the point where I create [Frame(factoryClass='path.to.class')] and I create Preloader.

But here now I dont know how to make a preloader that would load rsl's and then go to the next frame, or main class. What [Frame] tag does, is it makes two frames, one for preloader, and one for main class that should be executed after.

Config I pass to the compiler:

```
<flex-config>





   <!-- A list of runtime shared library URLs to be loaded before applications start. -->
   <!-- GreenSock -->
   <runtime-shared-library-path> 
    <path-element>/Users/matej/Documents/Projects/Work/External/greensock-as3/greensock.swc</path-element>
    <rsl-url>http://localhost/~matej/rsls/greensock.swf</rsl-url>
    <policy-file-url>http://localhost/~matej/rsls/crossdomain.xml</policy-file-url>
    <rsl-url>http://localhost/rsls/greensock.swf</rsl-url>
    <policy-file-url>http://localhost/rsls/crossdomain.xml</policy-file-url>

    </runtime-shared-library-path>


    <!-- static-link-runtime-shared-libraries: statically link the libraries specified by the -runtime-shared-libraries-path option.-->
    <static-link-runtime-shared-libraries>false</static-link-runtime-shared-libraries>





</flex-config>
```

main class

```
package {

import com.greensock.TweenLite;

import Preloader;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

[Frame(factoryClass="Preloader")]
public class RedSquare extends Sprite{

    //---------------------------------------------------------------
    //  Private variables
    //---------------------------------------------------------------
    private var redRectangle:Sprite;
    //---------------------------------------------------------------
    //  Constructor
    //---------------------------------------------------------------
    public function RedSquare() {


        redRectangle = new Sprite();
        redRectangle.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFF0000);
        redRectangle.graphics.drawRect(100,100,50,30);

        redRectangle.graphics.endFill();
        addChild(redRectangle);

        redRectangle.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,onOver);


    }

    //---------------------------------------------------------------
    //  Public methods
    //---------------------------------------------------------------

    //---------------------------------------------------------------
    //  Private methods
    //---------------------------------------------------------------

    private function onOver(event:MouseEvent):void {

        TweenLite.to(redRectangle,3,{x:400,y:200,rotation:160})

    }
}
}
```

Comment: At first I thought: "why don't you just set RSL as the dependency linkage in IntelliJ?". Then I tried to do just that myself. And eventually I found myself voting for this issue: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-80149... I really love IntelliJ, but I really can't understand that this feature is missing.

Comment: Yes. Now i wonder if you know how to manually do it, because you can add compiler config to intelliJ. I tried few stuff but it didn't work. If I manage to make it work I post it here.

Comment: I also miss this feature in IntelliJ !!!
Was hoping for it to come in the next version

Comment: Hi Guys, did any of you figure this out?